# Process Celery Tasks results in arrival order

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, amqp

I am new to celery, i have an "celery-server", like the code below which returns results after some time, depending on calculation. I have emulated this behaviour in this simple program below with the sleep function. What i want is to process the early returning results before the "heavy results". I have written a simple programm, see snipped below, which intentionally creates the "heavy load" task as first call.
Note that the subsequent calls create "lighter" tasks and therefore the celery server returns them earlier. Therefore i want to process the returning results based on the order they arrive at the client. Right now (see client code) it waits until the heavy tasks has returned.

But with the examples from celery docs, i am supposed to wait for results by checking the id, or poll for them (which is dumb, because  celery client has to check the id of the "first" arrived result somehow i guess).

How can I process the results of celery in the order they arrive at the client? I don't want to poll in an endless loop for "result.ready()"  as this completely screws up IMHO somehow the sense of aync processing.

Found no solution in the docs. What i want to do is "get first arrived resulted and get id", compare this to my "result.id" (did i send the task?) and then process accordingly.

```
#
# Name this code "tasks.py"  and run it with:
# celery worker -A tasks  --loglevel=info
#
from celery import Celery
import time
app = Celery('tasks', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1:5672/%2F')

@app.task()
def add(x,y):
  print("x=%s y=%s" % (x,y))
  time.sleep(x)
  return x + y
```

Second programm the client: This works like celery docs, howerver celery has already completed 0,1,2 (and therefore the client should work on it).

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from tasks import add

results = []
max = 4
for i in range(0,max):
  print(max-(i+1))
  result = add.delay(max-(i+1),0)
  results.append(result)

print("") 

for i in range(0,max):
  result = results[i].get(timeout=10)
  print(result)
```

Result: (the last 4 numbers should appear in arrival order which would be 0,1,2,3 )

```
3
2
1
0

3
2
1
0
```

Answer (score 1):

You should implement a callback rather than looping through the results in the order that they were sent to the queue:

http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#linking-callbacks-errbacks

In tasks.py:

```
@app.task()
def process_add(result):
    print(result)
```

In client.py:

```
from tasks import add, process_add
results = []
max = 4
for i in range(0,max):
    print(max-(i+1))
    add.apply_async((max-(i+1), 0), link=process_add.s())
```

Comment: after changing it to:

result = add.apply_async((max-(i+1), 0), link=process_at_client.s()  )

it just gives me a error on the server side, that process_at_client does not
exist.

it seems after docs that this only "linking"  functions on the server-side?

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  You need to add it in your tasks.py and add the task decorator.  Also no need to check for the result.  Corrected above.

Comment: No syntax error now. But still the process_add is executed on the server 
side and not on the receiving client side, which still needs to pull the 
results with resutls.get() : i can see that the tasks are linked on the server
side, so after add _on_ server , process_add is called _on_ server. but
actually i want this part running on the client... :-(

 [2015-09-11 08:43:21,096: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.add[fd1d64ad-3d02-4a9b-9a38-0b2fd0511eaf] succeeded in 0.024234951997641474s: 0
[2015-09-11 08:43:21,104: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.process_add[d89b6cef-155e-4c18-bf72-ccdd3bb69b1c] succ

Comment: It sounds like you're actually looking for asynchronous behavior in the client as well.  You need a way for the workers to trigger the caller asynchronously once they've processed the job.  This sounds an awful like another celery queue, only this time the worker is the "client".

Comment: i see where you going, this would require a lot of work to make the clients "post-procssing"  task a celery task on the server and massive transfer of information between client and celery-server.  Sigh - not an option

Comment: How many simultaneous tasks are you expecting to send?  Is it feasible to fork a thread in the client for each one and have that block on the result (like in the inside of your for loop)?  This would be asynchronous and wouldn't require a ton of celery overhead, but would get out of control with lots of tasks.

Comment: it depends on some days 10 but on peeks up to 10000 requests (produced at the same time). With the different run-time of each request, it would optimal to start with "whatever gets back first".... i am not sure that threading would be a solution,as the client musst process them all before continuing, unfortunatly i just run in the situation, that with the current implementation, the clients waits for the longest running task to finish and then start processing already finished tasks (which could have been processed easily before - and i have no way to predict which tasks runs long.